# Jinja2 how to rename a expression value

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I'm using jinja2 to render string. I have a filter named 'get_user_by_id' and other similar filters. I want to rename the filter expression value with a simple variable name. The follow is what I want:

```
{% rename 1|get_user_by_id, 'user'%}
{{user.name}} {{user.email}} ...

{% rename 5|get_book_by_id, 'book'%}
{{book.name}} {{book.price}} ...
```

How can I write the "rename" tag extension with jinja2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand is that you try to set a new variable in jinja...
You can do it with `set` command.
For example:

`{% set book = get_user_by_id %}`